# Bootstrap Carousel issue - elements on top flashing

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm creating a site in Bootstrap (3.3.5 or whatever the latest version is) and I'm using the carousel feature to fade between background images on one of the pages.

Firstly I'm using this CSS to adjust the Bootstrap Carousel to fade out and in, instead of sliding.

```
.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .item {
    opacity: 0;
    transition-property: opacity;

}

.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .active {
    opacity: 1;
}

.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .active.left,
.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .active.right {
    left: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}

.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .next.left,
.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .prev.right {
    opacity: 1;
}

.carousel-fade .carousel-control {
    z-index: 2;
}

@media all and (transform-3d), (-webkit-transform-3d) {
    .carousel-fade .carousel-inner > .item.next,
    .carousel-fade .carousel-inner > .item.active.right {
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
        transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    }
    .carousel-fade .carousel-inner > .item.prev,
    .carousel-fade .carousel-inner > .item.active.left {
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
        transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    }
    .carousel-fade .carousel-inner > .item.next.left,
    .carousel-fade .carousel-inner > .item.prev.right,
    .carousel-fade .carousel-inner > .item.active {
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
        transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    }
}
```

My problem is, I have thing positioned `absolute`, on top of the carousel. As the carousel switches between images, the things on top of it also fade out and in. This obviously isn't what I want to happen.

My HTML:

```
<div class="big-banner">
    <div class="carousel slide carousel-fade" id="carousel-home" data-ride="carousel1">
    </div> <!-- carousel -->
    <div class="container">
    </div> <!-- /.container -->
</div> <!-- /.big-banner -->
```

The stuff in `.container` is what I have placed over the carousel.

Anyone know a solution?

Comment: post your HTML. also, why not just take your element that has the `position:absolute` and move it outside the `item` element(s)?

Comment: I've edited my post with the HTML.

Comment: you should do a fiddle. also you're missing CSS for `.container`

Comment: I'm using Bootstrap as stated, and haven't overwritten any defaults.

Comment: I'm still having this issue, elements that are over the top of the carousel flash when the carousel fades out and in.

Comment: make fiddle so it'll be easier to debug

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/omqwcw7t/

Answer (score 1):

Add `z-index:1000;` to `.overlay`. [Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/omqwcw7t/1/). The reason is b/c even though you have it `absolute` and not inside the carousel, they are both on the same "level", and `z-index` comes into play.

```
.overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index:1000;
}
```

Comment: I actually did this before, and it didn't completely work. Let me make an updated fiddle.

Comment: I'll update because you did answer my question, but it's not working for my situation. I'll try and fix it myself, it'll take too long to create a fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

See if this works for you.
Also, the 4th `<li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="4"></li>` is missing so I added it.

```css
.overlay {
  top: 0;
  font-size: 60px;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 10;
  pointer-events: none;
}
.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .item {
  opacity: 0;
  transition-property: opacity;
}
.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .active {
  opacity: 1;
}
.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .active.left,
.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .active.right {
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}
.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .next.left,
.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .prev.right {
  opacity: 1;
}
.carousel-fade .carousel-control {
  z-index: 2;
}
@media all and (transform-3d),
(-webkit-transform-3d) {
  .carousel-fade .carousel-inner > .item.next,
  .carousel-fade .carousel-inner > .item.active.right {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }
  .carousel-fade .carousel-inner > .item.prev,
  .carousel-fade .carousel-inner > .item.active.left {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }
  .carousel-fade .carousel-inner > .item.next.left,
  .carousel-fade .carousel-inner > .item.prev.right,
  .carousel-fade .carousel-inner > .item.active {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }
}
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .overlay {
    font-size: 30px;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide carousel-fade" data-ride="carousel">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="4"></li>
  </ol>

  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <h1 class="overlay">OVERLAY</h1>
    <div class="item active">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/2000x1000/216091/fff" />
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/2000x1000/53a7ea/fff" />
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/2000x1000/266080/fff" />
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/2000x1000/f00/fff" />
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Controls -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>  <span class="sr-only">Previous</span> 
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>  <span class="sr-only">Next</span> 
  </a>
</div>
```